# Radio button click active color change using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

when we click on the radio button background color and label color will change I have written CSS but it is not working. Can anyone suggest me.

```js
const handleVisibility = (e) => {
  e.target.closest('.case-inner-info').querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]').forEach(i => i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
}
const allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");
allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})
```

```css
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #051326;
  z-index: 2;
}

.switch-input {
  display: none;
}

.switch-input:checked .switch-label {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  -o-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-off~.switch-selection {
  left: 60px;
}

.switch-selection {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}

.case-switch .switch-selection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On</label>
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your input is inside the label, and can't reach ~.switch-selection out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is inside the `label` element, and can't reach `~.switch-selection` out of it.

Can be fixed by moving an input out of the label, but it breaks the layout. As I don't know how it should look - here is a slightly broken working version.

PS: Pay attention to these selectors:

```
.switch-input[data-ref="on"]:checked ~ .switch-selection {
  background: green;
}
```

```js
const handleVisibility = (e) => {
  e.target.closest('.case-inner-info').querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]').forEach(i => i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
}
const allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");
allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})
```

```css
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #051326;
  z-index: 2;
}

.switch-input {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.switch-input:checked .switch-label {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition-property: color;
}


.switch-selection {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}

.case-switch .switch-selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}

// check out this selectors bellow

.switch-input[data-ref="on"]:checked ~ .switch-selection {
  background: green !important;
}

.switch-input[data-ref="off"]:checked ~ .switch-selection {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
<div class="inner_div">
  <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
    <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
    <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-switch">
  <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">On</label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
  
  <label class="switch-label switch-label-off"> Off</label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off"/>
 
  <span class="switch-selection"> </span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### UPD: Alternative version

```css
.wrap { 
  min-height: 3em;
  min-width: 5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}

.wrap input:checked ~ span {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
 <label class="wrap">
  Item 1
  <input type="radio" name="radio-101fm" checked/>
  <span></span>
</label>

<label class="wrap">
  Item 2
  <input type="radio" name="radio-101fm" checked/>
  <span></span>
</label>

<label class="wrap">
  Item 3
  <input type="radio" name="radio-101fm" checked/>
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do this actually  I'm trying to do with input inside the label

Comment: It is possible to do with my previous code.